# Auto-login a user to an external website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to securely save a user's credentials to related web sites and automatically log them into those sites when they log onto ours.  I understand there are some security implications to this, so I'd like others' feedback and see what has been successful for others in the past.

What technique have you used to auto-log the users in?  I'd prefer not to have to duplicate the HTML form and submit it through javascript.  This seems error-prone if the form ever changes.  I tried putting the login form inside an iframe, but it seems like the owners of the site are able to block this (see attached screenshot).  Do you know how they do this?

Secondly, what was your approach to save the credentials so that they were "safe".

...Peter

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this, out of curiosity?

Comment: @MaxPM Our users have many paid, business-related websites that they need to log into (not just twitter).  As part of the project, they've asked us to create a poor-man's SSO so that they don't have to sign in to those all the time.  We understand there are security and maintenance implications to this... we'd like to see how others have approached the problem

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using cookies to save a session certificate to the users machine. A good value for such a cookie would be;

**userid, timestamp, hash(userid . timestamp . global_secret)**

The value of **global_secret** needs to be very long (40 characters or so), to avoid people cracking the hash, as doing so would allow them to create their own credentials with other peoples user ids!

The 'other sites' would check for this cookie, calculate the hash using the cleartext values of **userid**, **timestamp** and the **global_secret** (which all sites know), check it against the hash supplied, if they match, then this is a valid certificate.

You would then need to check the timestamp and decide if this was a 'new' enough certificate to allow access.

This is the standard method.

Comment: How would the other sites check for the cookie? Cookies are set on a per domain (or narrower) basis, and the sites are "external".

Comment: Upon login, echo out a series of invisible iframes to each of the external sites. This could be centralised so that you wouldnt need to maintain separate lists. The iframe requests would contain a GET variable with the credential, which the external site could then echo back as a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not do this.**  Read the terms of services for each site (ie facebook):

https://www.facebook.com/terms.php?ref=pf

> (3.2) You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise **access Facebook, using automated means** (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission.
>
> (3.5) You will not solicit login information or **access an account belonging to someone else**.
>
> (4.8) You will not share your password, (or in the case of developers, your secret key), **let anyone else access your account**, or do anything else that might jeopardize the security of your account.

You put yourself and the user at risk.

These sites have an API for a reason, so I suggest you looking using those as a more "legal" approach.

So if you're trying to retrieve a facebook user's information, create an app, have them authorize your app, then retrieve the information through facebook's api ([example](http://graph.facebook.com/stevether)). *You can also post to their wall with this method.*

https://developers.facebook.com/

https://dev.twitter.com/

https://developers.google.com/

Comment: I'd have to agree with stevether, you may have to fight with Facebook's notoriously poorly documented API but that's definitely a safer approach (legally and security-wise). And if your employer still insists on doing it the former way I'd suggest finding a more reputable employer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... Note that we won't be logging people into typical user-facing sites such as Facebook or twitter.  We will be logging them into business-related sites which may (or may not) be more willing to let us do this.  We will evaluate that side of things once we find out if it is technically feasible to do with minimal maintenance/hackieness.

Answer (score 0):

The common method to auto login a user is to set an cookie with an random string. It have to be that the random string isn't guessable. At the server you check the cookie and if it matches then you login the user. But if your site isn't completely served with https everyone who can listen to the traffic can pretend to be the user. To increase the security a little bit you could implement that a random string is only valid for a view days and then the user has to login again and a new random string is generated. So if someone steals the cookie-id the attacker has only for a certain time access to the account.

Comment: How would the other sites check for the cookie? Cookies are set on a per domain (or narrower) basis, and the sites are "external".

Comment: Not other sites can get the cookie with Javascript (unless there is a security issue). E.g. if you are in an unencrypted wlan then everybody can read all your traffic (if it's not encrypted. e.g.: https). Form this traffic the attacker can extract everything he needs.

Comment: That's my point. My site can't set a cookie to log someone into your site.